# Chrome developer tools > resources > cookies > http column, does a checkmark here indicate HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, httponly

Does the checkmark at the Http column of Chrome devtool's Cookie resource panel indicate a HttpOnly cookie?

I can't find docs that confirm this, though I suspect it is the case. I am trying to verify my app is using HttpOnly for session cookies.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes. Enter [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) in the console, and you'll see that none of the checked cookies are visible.

[image: Name Value Domain Path Expires Size HTTP Secure]

HTTP = HttpOnly flag, Secure = secure flag.

Comment: i have one cookie variable as HTTP checked, i am not able to get that variable from document.cookie , all non HTTP checked variables are coming but not HTTP checked, Why so

Comment: @Vivek httpOnly cookies are only visible to the server, not to JavaScript code.

Answer (score 21):

Yes. Right click on your page or press `F12` button. This will open developers tools window. Go to application tab. It'll show as follow :-

[image]

Now, typing document.cookie on the tab, you'll see only csrf token being shown.[image]

To specify session cookies to be httpCookie by default, set `'useHttpOnly'` attribute in context.xml in tomcat, for java web application. For more information, refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

Answer (score 17):

So 2 things .

1) `HTTP only cookie` this name is a bit misleading as we can send HTTPOnly cookie over HTTPS and it works perfectly fine. Main characteristics of `HTTP Only` cookie is it can't be accessed using JavaScript . In-fact You can't even manually edit this in Chrome's `Application` tab.

2) So how you can edit HTTP Only cookie ? In chrome You can use [extension to edit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) cookie while development . In production mode there is no way you can adultrate this without `man in the middle` attack on HTTP connection.

Comment: #1 above is incorrect. In Chrome's dev tools I seem to be able to edit cookies with HTTP checked with no problem? They do not appear in document.cookies.

Comment: The cookie resets though after you refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

Today (May 2016), googling around for the same reason, I found this question and [this page from developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/manage-data/cookies#learn-about-each-cookie) explaining:

> HTTP: If present, indicates that cookies should be used only over HTTP, and JavaScript modification is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to visualize:

1. Install [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension.
2. Click the storageAce icon on this tab (the tab of current question).
3. Click the "HttpOnly" one-click quick filter.
4. All the filtered cookies are **HttpOnly** and you will see that HttpOnly cell is checked for each of these filtered cookies in the Developer Tools --> Application --> Cookies.

**HttpOnly cookies using StorageAce**
[image]

**HttpOnly cookies using Developer Tools**
[image]

If you need to see **Non-HttpOnly cookies**, then you can switch ON the **Invert Filter Toggle** as below:

[image]