# How to access HttpOnly cookies from Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Some cookies are marked as HttpOnly. See [Chrome developer tools > resources > cookies > http column, does a checkmark here indicate HttpOnly cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378025/chrome-developer-tools-resources-cookies-http-column-does-a-checkmark-her)

If I use this code inside the debug console to get all cookies:

```
document.write(document.cookie)
```

Then it gives me everything except the HttpOnly cookies, which because my code is running inside the javascript environment and the design of HttpOnly is to hide it from the javascript environment.

Is there another option to use the Chrome console to get *all* the cookies?

I am hoping to get this in the same format as the above line of code produces.

Comment: Currently I use a proxy (Charles proxy) to send this request through and I pick up the cookies from the wire. There has got to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Related: how to access chrome dev tools pane javascript environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875605/debugging-chrome-extension-with-access-to-chrome-devtools-api