# Why do Cookie overview outputs differ in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

First i look in the console with the command:
`document.cookie`. There are four Elements.

[image]

Then i look in "developer Tools" - "Application" - "Cookies" - "stackoverflow"

[image]

**Question:**

Why are there more Cookies displayed in the latter view.

Comment: Probably cookies inherited from other pages on the site.

Comment: this also seem to explain a bit (but not not all): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40671502/3502164

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378025) it can be assumed that some of those cookies are HTTP cookies which do not get set in `document.cookie` (these cookies are passed through HTTP headers).

Comment: thanks for your answer. As mentioned in the comment above i think it only can answer partially. If you take a look at the Httponly Distribution there are 7 with httponly checkmark and 10 without, But in the console i only see four. I will update the grafic.