# Why is my HTTP-only cookie undefined after page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, cookie-httponly

I'm setting an HTTP-only cookie to JWT token, then when I'm refreshing the page on frontend. It automatically calls endpoint which has getCheckToken on it. When I try to retrieve that set HTTP-only cookie it returns undefined. This happens when I send the request from my app on localhost:3000, When I use Postman and send a request first on /login and then on /check-token, it works perfectly there, and logs the cookie as it should.

login controller:

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then((user) => {
      bcrypt
        .compare(password, user.password)
        .then((isMatching) => {
          if (!isMatching)
            return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Incorrect email or password" });

          const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "1h",
          });

          res.cookie("JWT_TOKEN", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
          });

          const userData = {
            userName: user.userName
          };

          return res.send({ userData });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({ msg: "An error occurred while logging in." });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send({ msg: "An error occurred while logging in." });
    });
};
```

checkToken controller:

```
exports.getCheckToken = async (req, res) => {
  let token = req.cookies["JWT_TOKEN"];
  console.log(token);

  res.send();
}
```

index.js file:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { MONGO_URL, PORT } = process.env;

const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(authRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(MONGO_URL)
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

frontend custom hook:

```
const useCheckToken = () => {
  const updateUserData = useStore((state) => state.updateUserData);
  const { data: userData, isLoading } = useQuery("checkToken", verifyAuthToken);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      updateUserData(userData);
    }
  }, [userData, updateUserData]);

  return { userData, isLoading };
};
```

verifyAuthToken function:

```
export const verifyAuthToken = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${apiBase}/check-token`, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return res.data.userData;
};
```

Comment: Post login (before page refresh), can you take a look in the browser's (chrome) Application tab to see if the cookie was actually set in the first place.

Comment: @remedy_man I cant see any cookie there, but its HTTP only cookie which shouldn't be available there anyway. When I use postman and send request first on /login and then on /check-token, it works perfectly there, logs cookie as it should.

Comment: It is visible in the browser application tab --> [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378025/chrome-developer-tools-resources-cookies-http-column-does-a-checkmark-her). Its most likely the client domain is different from the server's. Can you add the client's domain in `res.cookie` for example `res.cookie("JWT_TOKEN", token, { domain: 'localhost', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 })`.

Comment: @remedy_man added "localhost" domain, but still the same outcome. No cookie is shown in the browser application tab either :(

Comment: @remedy_man I manually added JWT_TOKEN from browser application tab and I do receive it in backend /check-token route. I guess its not setting it /login route but idk why, no error nothing, I logged and token does get generated there. Is there any way I can check it?

Comment: @remedy_man backend runs on localhost:5000, frontend on localhost:3000 can that cause that ?

Comment: It shouldnt cause an issue as long as you set the domain to 'localhost'.  Can you log the response header you receive once postLogin request is fulfilled? In particular can you paste the `set-cookie` header if it exists.

Comment: @remedy_man 
`const res = await axios.post(`${apiBase}/login`, userData);
 console.log(res.headers);
`
=> { "content-length": "435", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }

Comment: Seems the set-cookie directive is missing in transit. Can you remove `allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],` cors config so it defaults to your request's Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Comment: @remedy_man same outcome

Comment: @remedy_man Im wondering why is it working on Postman perfectly

Comment: @remedy_man fixed it finally, `export const login = async (userData) => {
  const res = await axios.post(`${apiBase}/login`, userData, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  console.log(res.headers);
  return res.data;
};`
on my /login API call I had no {withCredentials:true} as it wasnt reading any cookies. but axios needs it everywhere anyway :@@

Comment: Makes perfect sense. You did not provide code for your login request hence I did not verify this. To make life easier for yourself you can create a convenience `axios` instance and provide default config. `export const axiosInstance = axios.create({ withCredentials: true })`. Prevent you from subscribing to credentials on each request.